# Recurrence relations - finding optimal way to solve it

Tags: matrices, algorithms, recurrence-relations

I've found a very interesting algorithmic problem that looks like this.

Given the first row of a $(m \times n)$ $0$-indexed matrix ($m$ rows, $n$ columns), find the last row of the matrix, using this recurrence relations :

> $$a_{i,j} = a_{i-1,j}\oplus a_{i-1,j+1 (\forall j : 0 \leq j \leq n-2)}$$
>   $$ a_{i,  n-1} = a_{i-1, n-1} \oplus a_{i-1,0}$$

Of course, an $O(n^2)$ algorithm that simply generates row after row until the final one is obtained is out of the question. I'm basically looking for a $O(n)$ solution that finds the last row by simply processing the first row through employing some mathematical tricks or noticing and patterns I can't see right now.

Through inspection, I found out that the constituents of $a_{i,j}$ become cyclical after a while, but combining this into a program gives a really nasty run-time.

As an example, given $6,7,1,3$ is the first row of a $(2 \times 4)$ matrix, the last row would be $1,6,2,5$.

Any ideas? I'm quite  sure this has a neat solution that I'm anxious to see but my efforts in expanding terms and noticing patterns hasn't paid off yet.

Comment: What does the $\oplus$ stand for?

Comment: It's bitwise xor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that for any $n$ we have $a_{n+2^k,j}=a_{n,j}\oplus a_{n,(j+2^k\mod m)}$.

We show it by induction on $k$. $k=0$ is direct. Assume that for any $n$ we have $a_{n+2^k,j}=a_{n,j}\oplus a_{n,(j+2^k\mod m)}$. Let $n'$ be an integer we have:
$$a_{n'+2^{k+1},j}=a_{(n'+2^{k})+2^k,j}$$
hence by induction hypothesis
$$a_{n'+2^{k+1},j}=a_{(n'+2^{k}),j}\oplus a_{(n'+2^{k}),(j+2^k\mod m)}$$hence by induction hypothesis
$$a_{n'+2^{k+1},j}=a_{n',j}\oplus a_{n',(j+2^k\mod m)}\oplus a_{n',(j+2^k\mod m)}\oplus a_{n',(j+2^k+2^k\mod m)}$$
$$ = a_{n',j}\oplus a_{n',(j+2^{k+1}\mod m)}$$

This should improve your algorithm.

Comment: can you please explain the definition of $a_{n, 0}$ ?

Comment: also, we can't find $a_{n, 1}$ with your current definition

Comment: Thank you, look forward to seeing any useful results

Comment: @programmer101 I patched my mistake ...

Comment: I really don't see how this helps in finding the last row.

Comment: @programmer101 it avoid commuting all the rows. If $n=2^k$ then you can compute the last row directly. if $n=2^k+n'$ with $n'<2^k$ than you can compute row $2^k$ and you are left with the same problem but for $n'$. Thus you only have to compute in the worst case $\lfloor log(n)\rfloor+1$  rows (when $n=2^k-1$) instead of $n$ and in the best case only one row (when $n=2^k$).